# Get database through email id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Controller[In Article Page Article Properly work with pagination, store user email id in 'articles' database , now i tried to get the user firstname, and lastname from users table but not work properly  ]

```
  public function articles()
   {    
    $data['title'] = "Articles";

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "sd/articles/";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->model_users->record_count_articles();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->model_users->fetch_result_articles($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    if ($this->session->userdata ('is_logged_in')){
        $data['profile']=$this->model_users->profilefetch();
        $this->load->view('sd/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('sd/articles', $data);
        $this->load->view('sd/footer', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('sd/sdheader', $data);
        $this->load->view('sd/articles', $data);
        $this->load->view('sd/sdfooter', $data);
    }
}
```

Model [ Get Users Name in Article Page ]

```
     public function record_count_articles() {
           return $this->db->where('status','1')->count_all("articles");
       }

    public function fetch_result_articles($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->where('status','1')->order_by('id', 'DESC')->get("articles");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;

            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Add These Lines [ But Not Work]

```
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
                $query = $this->db->select('firstname')->select('lastname')->where('email',$data[0]->email)->get("users");
                $data['name_info']=$query->result_array();
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: change this $row->email instead data[0]->email and also comment this line // $data[] = $row;

Comment: Only First Article Name get , name array is not repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problem here.  please have a look on comments in code.

```
 if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                //1) $data[0]->email keep repeating same email.
                //   inner $query variable should be different.  
                $innerQuery = $this->db->select('firstname,lastname')->where('email',$row->email)->get("users");
                //2) you need to store query result on array.
                // $data['name_info'] stores only single record.
                $data[]=$innerQuery ->result_array();
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
```

**You should avoid query in loop if you can achieve it by join**

**EDIT: Lets try this with join**

```
public function fetch_result_articles($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db
      ->join('users u','u.email = a.email','left')
      ->where('a.status','1')->order_by('a.id', 'DESC')->get("articles a");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;

            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have not tested the code. but it is better way than loop.

Comment: Your code is help full array is properly repeat but problem is that I need Article data so ill add these lines, """    $data[] = $row;  """, my first article print in [0] and name print in [1], second article print in [2] and name print in [3]

Comment: Can you show me how your outer `$query` written? not `$innerQuery`

Comment: Thanks Man , 'join' way is perfectly working , Thanks :)